# About.me App for SO

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, jobs

I'd like to be able to add my Stack Overflow and/or SO Careers profile as an 'app' to my [about.me](http://about.me/) page, a la Twitter, LinkedIn, etc.

Is this in the works? I have no idea what the API looks like, but it'd be a neat thing to have. I love SO, and am proud to be a contributor, and I think it'd be cool to be able to share it on about.me.

Comment: If they have an RSS reader, you could just add in your [user feed](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/344143). I don't see them implementing any other form of "app" to view this information, not that this really has anything to do with About.me (that just happens to be where you'd put it). We also have [flair images](http://stackoverflow.com/users/344143/ben-mosher/flair).

Comment: An app would be more convenient indeed. What I did was add my careers account as regular link. To include my answers, I ran my user feed through a Yahoo Pipe to limit it to answers only and then included that as RSS on my [about.me page](http://about.me/gooh).

Answer (score 2):

Upon further inspection, you can add arbitrary links to about.me; I added my careers profile this way.

An app for SO to display recent questions/answers would be neat, but is not a huge value-add over just linking to a careers or normal SO profile page.

I'd just delete the question, but I'm curious if anyone else has ideas/opinions surrounding about.me.